# Toolbar not displaying correctly

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am fairly new to android development and I'm having an issue with one of the last activities I had to create before I complete my first app. The toolbar in my Browse Results class is displaying at an incorrect size.
[Here is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D15mf.png)

Here is my activity_browse_results.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_valid_acronym"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:context="com.redacted.CSRenA.acronymlookup.BrowseResults">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewA"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewA"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewB"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewA"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_share"
        android:contentDescription="Share button. Click to share this Glossary Term and Definition"
        android:text="Share"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/home3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/home3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_home"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/asdkjf"
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewB"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView300"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_logo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/share2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/eagle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_browse_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my content_browse_results.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.redacted.CSRenA.acronymlookup.BrowseResults"
   >
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please let me know if any other information is required to help resolve this problem.

Comment: Simply don't add padding to the root layout (the RelativeLayout)

Comment: This fixed the width issue but the bar height is still a bit small even though I have it set to 56dp. Any ideas?

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks like your ConstraintLayout is drawn on top of everything else (last element in a RelativeLayout), so the Toolbar you'll see is the one from content_browse_results.xml For this Toolbar you did not specify a height of 56dp. If I'm on the wrong track there, my advice is to use LayoutInspector (AndroidStudio: Tools->Android->LayoutInspector) and verify that things are where you expect them to be.

Comment: It did have to do with the layout. There were extra unneeded parameters dealing with the toolbar layout in my activity_browse_results class. Thank you so much for your assistance! You should post your comments as the answer so that I can give you credit for answering my question,

Comment: Thank you, but I think you did most of the work :)

Answer (score 0):

[0X0nosugar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015207/0x0nosugar) really helped me with this answer. To solve the issue, I removed the padding in the RelativeLayout. The padding was pushing the toolbar down since it was inside of the RelativeLayout. After this, the only issue left was the height of the toolbar as it was shorter that usual although the width issue was corrected. To solve this, I removed the following code from the AppBarLayout tag.

```
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewA"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
```

After doing that, the toolbar displayed correctly.